# web.config and .htaccess in root folder?

Tags: .htaccess, web-config

I currently have a web.config & htaccess file in my root directory.
They basically both contain the same information, is it okay to have them both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is IIS 7 or above, then migrate all the settings to the web.config file and get rid of the htaccess file.